# File.length() returns 0 at first, but later returns the correct value

Tags: android, image, filesize

I am trying to get the file size of an image I've downloaded and saved using this `AsyncTask`

```
protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
      String urldisplay = params[0];

      if(params[1] != null)
          newClan = params[1];

      if(params[2] != null){
          Context ctx = Home.getContext();

          prevClan = params[2];
          File f  = new File(ctx.getFilesDir(), prevClan + ".png");
          if(f.exists()){
              File d = f.getAbsoluteFile();
              d.delete();
          }
      }

      Bitmap emblem = null;

        try {
            //get emblem from url
            InputStream  in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            emblem = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(e.getClass().toString(), e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(e.getClass().toString(), e.getMessage());
        }

      return emblem;
  }

  public static void saveImage(Bitmap img){

      Context ctx = Home.getContext();

      try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(ctx.getFilesDir().getPath() + File.separatorChar + newClan + ".png");
        img.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    } catch (NullPointerException e1) {
        Log.e("NullPointerException DownloadImageTask", e1.toString());//TODO
    }
  }
```

This is called like so

```
File emblemPath = new File(ctx.getFilesDir(), clan + ".png");
    Log.e("image size", emblemPath.length()+"");//TODO

    if(emblemPath.exists()){
        emb.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(emblemPath.toString()));
        Log.e("Image exists", "size = " + emblemPath.length());//TODO
    }
    else{
        String prevClan = pref.getString("prevClan", null);
        emb.setImageBitmap(Storage.updateClanEmb(embURL, clan, prevClan));
        Log.e("Image downloaded", "size = " + emblemPath.length());//TODO
    }
```

I have a login screen directly before this that supplies the needed variables. The downloaded image shows correctly in the `ImageView` but the file size is 0 the first time, after logging out and then back in, it shows the correct file size. The log is here:

```
- 05-25 04:52:32.973: E/result(22501): {"login":0,"clan":"Cosa Nostra","status":"0"}
- 05-25 04:52:32.984: E/Login success!(22501): Login success!
- 05-25 04:52:34.554: E/image size(22501): 0
- 05-25 04:52:35.953: E/Image downloaded(22501): size = 0
- 05-25 04:52:44.553: E/Logout(22501): Logged out
- 05-25 04:52:54.893: E/result(22501): {"login":0,"clan":"Cosa Nostra","status":"0"}
- 05-25 04:52:54.893: E/Login success!(22501): Login success!
- 05-25 04:52:57.034: E/image size(22501): 2461
- 05-25 04:52:57.094: E/Image exists(22501): size = 2461
```

Why is the file size not correct after saving the image? Am I accessing it wrong? As a side note, I'm a newbie at Android and haven't fully grasped how to use contexts. I fear this might be my issue. In the code, Home is the activity that this is being called from.

**EDIT:**
I added this line to the `onPostExecute()` at @Samarth's request

`iv.setImageBitmap(result);`

where `iv` is the `ImageView` that displays the downloaded image. The resulting log was exactly the same. Could someone explain the advantage of setting the image in the `AsyncTask's onPostExecute()` method? I seem to have forgotten to include my `updateClanEmblem` method so here it is:

```
/**
 * Method to call DownloadImageTask which downloads then saves the updated clan emblem
 * 
 * @param iv The ImageView to set the emblem to
 * @param url The URL, as a String, to the page containing ONLY the clan emblem.
 * @param newClan The new clan emblem to download.
 * @param prevClan The old clan emblem to delete. Can be null.
 */
public static void updateClanEmb(ImageView iv, String url, String newClan, String prevClan){
    String[] params = {
            url,
            newClan,
            prevClan,
    };

    try {
        new DownloadImageTask(iv).execute(params).get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of struggle, I've found my solution. The `AsyncTask` hadn't finished before I tried to check the file size. I was under the impression that the `.get()` method would make it wait until it was done, but I was wrong. The reason I did not catch this sooner was that I made a mistake and was checking the wrong file in the `AsyncTask` so was getting misleading information.

What I've learned from this: the `.get()` method of the `AsyncTask` does not always wait for the task to finish. Do whatever needs to be done in the `onPostExecute()` method or else it will not work as expected. I am still unsure what the `.get()` method does.

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing the image saving and assigning in the onPostExecute method of the AsyncTask. I think you are trying to set the image before it is being downloaded.

When are you calling that piece of code. Also when are you calling saveImage?

Comment: The call to the AsyncTask is done in the `onCreate` of the Home activity. `saveImage` is called in the `onPostExecute` of the Async.

I will edit the AsyncTask to your suggestion and try again.

Comment: Since my comment can only be edited for 5 mins, I needed to make another one. I assign the `Bitmap` to the `ImageView` in the Home activity, outside of the AsyncTask. If I was trying to set the image before it was downloaded, would I still be able to see it? The image still appears correctly. I did not change my code, I realized this after I posted my previous comment.

Comment: Set the image immediately after saving the Bitmap within the post execute method. Setting image view outside of the asynctask has the disadvantage of not knowing when the image has downloaded. An `AsyncTask` is an asynchronous task as the name suggests.

Comment: Obviously. I call it using the `.get()` method so I thought it would avoid all that since it is supposed to wait until the task is finished to return. I will move it then try again. Just to keep everything clear, the image displays correctly every time, that is not my issue. My problem is the return value of the `emblemPath.length()` calls.

Comment: I added a check in the `AsyncTask` to read the file size directly after it is saved and it also returns 0. The curious thing is, the log for that displays after the log for "Image downloaded", which is made after the call to the Async. That would make sense if it wasn't supposed to be waiting for it to complete because of the `.get()` call. Do I not understand the function of `.get()`?